# How to recreate this gradient?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gradient

I saw a similar question has been asked but did not have a good answer. I want to recreate the gradient on the screenshot I attached. I couldn't figure out this hard gradient effect.

[image: Gradient example]

I have tried doing the hard gradient using an angle gradient but there was no fade between the white and the grey. I ended up just duplicating the white cell transforming the height to half the white cell and putting a grey to white gradient on the half cell. This gave me a hard gradient with a slight fade.

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/photoshop/cs/using/WSfd1234e1c4b69f30ea53e41001031ab64-77e1a.html

Answer (score 5):

If you look at the default Photoshop gradients, you will see one with blue and yellowish tones. You can probably use this gradient (changing the colors), or create a new one that imitates the color stops:

[image]

It's actually 2 or 3 gradients in one, 4 or 5 color stops. So your result would look something like this:

[image]